# Is it ok to use for each loop in View (alternatives)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I read that it is bad practice to use any logic in View when coding MVC. But normally I created tables by using **`for each`** this way:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(of ViewModel)
<table>Prop1
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Prop1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Prop2)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @For Each item In Model
            @<text>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Prop1)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Prop2)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </text>
       Next
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there an alternative way, or is this little logic ok?

Comment: it's what the default list<t> scaffold template does so i would assume it's perfectly fine.   i wouldn't really consider this "logic" either

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  Where did you read this?

Comment: The word logic is too broad, you have to be more specific. Business logic should be out of the view (ex: calculating total price of items), displaying logic should be in the view (ex: looping to display items).

Comment: @stephen.vakil I shold have written "heard". [Here](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-8322) Christopher Harrison stated: "If you bring logic in your view, you might be doing the wrong Thing." So, I was wondering, if a simple `for each` statement is ok.

Comment: @JamieD77 You are certainly right. Maybe this kind of logic is called "displaying logic" according to the_lotus or "output logic" as Zohaib Waqar stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the reason for the logic. If the logic is choosing an alternate presentation based on some property passed to it by the controller, it is probably ok. This allows you some view reuse. Instead of having to recreate (and repeat) an entire view for each custom privilege, you can pass in some data that allows the view to be customized based on this privilege.

I think of this as a pragmatic balance between an idealized **MVC** and strict enforcement of **DRY** (don't repeat yourself). In some situations it is wiser to violate one or the other if you can't attain both easily. In the case where clearly the model and the basic view is the same, putting a little logic in the view to keep your views DRY is reasonable.

The Logic you used is balanced. **And he statement you passed that it is not better to use logic in View is correct** but in case of Business logic.

the MVC parts are. In short, they are:

**Model** = domain logic

**View** = output logic

**Controller** = input logic

But the conditional statements can be used. Even you can populate you View by using some iteration statements.. 
Nothing wrong with it,

Comment: Thank you. I usually have the problem to decide whether to follow the rules of MVC or DRY. Your statement _View = output_ logic makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may have read is that you shouldn't have business logic in your view that could be executed within your controller.

You should perform operations that set the values of your Model within your controllers and then pass it to your view.  The view should generally not require any further processing other than to render your page, therefore looping around lists and other objects in order to display them on the page is acceptable and required.

If the code that you have in your view is generic and reusable across multuple views, I would recommend creating a HTML helper that you can reuse, this will make your views a lot cleaner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the tip with HTML herlpers. I definitely should think about using more of them.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are binding the view to the model at server side, it is the right way.

 Another alternative is to bind the view in client side, which I think is a very good practice. AngularJs is the beast library for doing that. You just retrieve pure html and you get the model as a json and bind the view with pure javascript object using angular.

https://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I agree that conditionals regarding the view model data should reside within the view model, and you should avoid having it in your views.

However a simple for each loop where you are only rendering the same markup for a list of items this is perfectly acceptable.

Even if you used seperate partial views or display/editor templates at some point you would have to iterate thourhg a list of items to generate repeated markup.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I've heard and read about good practices in MVC for ViewModel Binding, it is a good practice to have it. ViewModel Binding helps in maintaining relationship between the model and controller. Rather than displaying it using any other approach like ViewBag or ViewData, using ViewModel Binding is more optimized approach.
I think bad practice is using multiple linq queries in View

For eg.

```
  @Model.Where(x=>x.Column1.Equals("1")).Select(y=>y.column2)
```

If you have a simple foreach loop, looping over the model, that is a good practice as you're not performing any linq queries on the model

PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I'M WRONG